# Advisory locks scope in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql and trying to understand advisory locks. I have the following two scenarios:

1. With different databases in two different sessions: (Works in expected manner)

   Session 1: `SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1);` Successfully acquires the lock

   Session 2 (note in different database): `SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1);` Successfully acquires the lock
2. With Different Schemas in same database: When I do the same operation, the second 'session' blocks.

It appears that advisory locks operate at database level rather than (database and schema) combination. Is my assumption correct or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: "rather than (database and schema) " --- you don't specify schema anywhere in your query. Assuming this would be true, how would it know what schema to obtain the lock for?

Comment: They have the same "scope" as regular locks: per database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres schema is a namespace. More than just a prefix, but less than another database. in your case two, second session not "blocks", but rather is waiting as [per docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html):

> If another session already holds a lock on the same resource
>   identifier, this function will wait until the resource becomes
>   available.

Regarding  successful locking on different databases:
After you run `SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1);` checkout `pg_locks`, [column objid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-locks.html)

> OID of the lock target within its system catalog, or null if the
>   target is not a general database object

So this number is per database - you can reference same **1** for many databases - those will be different OIDs.